# double-tail Bayesian "p value" à la MCMCglmm

Tags: bayesian, p-value

The widely used MCMCglmm package for R, which implements Bayesian Markov chain Monte Carlo estimation for generalized linear mixed models, computes a "pMCMC" value
$$
p_{\textrm{MCMC}}(\beta) = 2 \times \min\left( \textrm{Prob}(\beta>0), \textrm{Prob}(\beta<0) \right)
$$
which is a crude analogue of the frequentist 2-tailed $p$-value. The package author (Jarrod Hadfield) has [commented](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q3/016815.html) that

> [It's] not a p-value as such, and better ways of obtaining Bayesian p-values exist.

In one of Hadfield's papers (Hadfield et al. 2013) he defines it as

> twice the posterior probability that the estimate is negative or positive (whichever probability is smallest)

(Unfortunately, some tutorials on MCMCglmm, and papers using it, have defined $p_{\textrm{MCMC}}$ as the "probability that the estimate does not differ from zero" (!!))

$p_{\textrm{MCMC}}$ could also be defined as $2 (1-p_D)$ where $p_D$ is the *probability of direction*, "the proportion of the posterior distribution that is of the median’s sign"  (Makowski et al. 2019).

I am headed toward presenting $p_{\textrm{MCMC}}$ values in a paper, and am curious

- whether anyone has seen this approach used elsewhere/more formally defined
- suggestions for other useful Bayesian $p$-value analogues that will be reasonably interpretable by non-statisticians (I am *not* interested in model comparison methods, or in [Bayesian p-values for diagnosing model adequacy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171386/what-are-bayesian-p-values))

---

Hadfield, Jarrod D., Elizabeth A. Heap, Florian Bayer, Elizabeth A. Mittell, and Nicholas M. A. Crouch. “Intraclutch Differences in Egg Characteristics Mitigate the Consequences of Age-Related Hierarchies in a Wild Passerine.” Evolution 67, no. 9 (2013): 2688–2700.

Makowski, Dominique, Mattan S. Ben-Shachar, S. H. Annabel Chen, and Daniel Lüdecke. “Indices of Effect Existence and Significance in the Bayesian Framework.” Frontiers in Psychology 10 (2019). https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.02767.

Comment: @statmerkur, would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Elaboration would be nice but just posting what you've got in the comment would certainly suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [Reconnecting *p*-Value and Posterior Probability Under One- and Two-Sided Tests](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epub/10.1080/00031305.2020.1717621) by Shi and Yin (2021) useful.

They show interesting connections between the two-sided posterior probability $\mathrm{{PoP}_2}$ and the (frequentist) *p*-value if flat or "non-informative" priors are used. In particular, $\mathrm{{PoP}_2}$ for two independent samples with normally or Bernoulli distributed outcomes is defined as
$$
\mathrm{{PoP}_2}=2[1-\max{\{\mathbb{P}(\beta<0|\mathrm{data}),\mathbb{P}(\beta>0|\mathrm{data})\}}],
$$
where $\beta$ is the difference of the two population means.